# XML Schema for sequence order/restriction based on attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

Is it possible to define in XML Schema a sequence order/restriction based on attribute value? 
In XML, there is `container` node which keeps only `item` nodes. First `item` node is always `delimiter`, other `item` nodes must be only with attribute value **`category1`** OR **`category2`**.

For example, valid documents is:

```
<root>
  <container>
    <item attr="delimiter">some_value</item>
    <item attr="category1">test1</item>
    <item attr="category1">test2</item>
    ....
  </container>

  <container>
    <item attr="delimiter">some_value</item>
    <item attr="category2">test3</item>
    ...
  </container>
<root>
```

In **`container`** node we can have `item` nodes only with **`category1`** or **`category2`**.

Example of incorrect XML:

```
<root>
  <container>
    <item attr="delimiter">some_value</item>
    <item attr="category1">test1</item>
    <item attr="category2">test2</item>
  </container>

  <container>
    <item attr="delimiter">some_value</item>
    <item attr="category2">test3</item>
    <item attr="category1">test1</item>
  </container>
<root>
```

Is it possible in XSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question directly, yes, this is possible in XSD, however:

1. It requires XSD 1.1 (see *XSD 1.1 for Original XML* below); it cannot be done in XSD 1.0:
2. It is poor XML design.  Better would be as follows, which could easily be represented in XSD 1.0:

   ```
   <root>
     <container>
       <delimiter>some_value</delimiter>
       <category1>test1</category1>
       <category1>test2</category1>
       ....
     </container>

     <container>
       <delimiter>some_value</delimiter>
       <category2>test3</category2>
       ...
     </container>
   </root>
   ```

### XSD 1.1 for Requested, Original XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="container" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute name="attr" use="required">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="delimiter"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="category1"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="category2"/>
                          </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                      </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="item[1]/@attr = 'delimiter' and
              ((every $i in item[position() > 1] satisfies $i/@attr = 'category1') or
               (every $i in item[position() > 1] satisfies $i/@attr = 'category2'))  "/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```